# Output in mysql is 0 when input passed through json variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, handlebars.js

I have a query:

The data rendering from JSON takes palce as :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="waterfall-tpl"> {{#result}} <?php echo {{img_id}}; ?> {{/result}}
```

Which I have used as:

```
$tty= utf8_decode('217');   
  $tty = str_replace("'","","$tty");
  $tty1 = "'".$tty;
  $tty2 = $tty1."'";


$number = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select count(user_id) from `comments` where    `img_id`=".$tty2));
  print_r($number);
```

In this case, $tty2 resolves to '217' and the output array $number is resolved as expected i.e.:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [count(user_id)] => 2 )
```

However, when I pass a json variable input (using Handlebars.js) as:

```
     $tty= utf8_decode('{{img_id}}');   
     $tty = str_replace("'","","$tty");
     $tty1 = "'".$tty;
     $tty2 = $tty1."'";

 $number = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select count(user_id) from `comments` where `img_id`=".$tty2));
 print_r($number);
```

In this case, $tty2 resolves to **'217'** and the output array $number is resolved as :

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [count(user_id)] => 0 )
```

The array output  should give me the value 2, but is giving 0.

The complete code:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="waterfall-tpl">


        {{#result}}
        <div class="item">

            <a title ="<u>{{title}}</u></br>{{story}}" 

               class="fancybox" href="{{image}}" rel="gallery"><img src="{{image}}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" alt = ""/> </a>       

            <span style="color:#868686;font-size:13px;"><b>{{title}}</b>&nbsp</span> |&nbsp <span style="color:#8A8A8A;font-size:12px" >Uploaded by: {{user_name}}</span> <hr />
            <!-- <span style="color:#8A8A8A;font-size:12px;line-height:120%;display:block;padding-top:7px;padding-bottom:7px;">{{story}} </span> -->

            <span class = "up">
                <a href="" class = "dup"><b>+53</b></a></br> 
                <a href="" class = "ddown"><b class = "td">-26</b></a>  
            </span>


            <div class="comment-wrapper">

                <div class="comment-insert">

                    <div class="comment-insert-container" 
                         style="position: relative;
                         margin: 0px;
                         border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
                         min-height: 66px;
                         width: auto;"> 
                        <textarea id="{{textarea_id}}" class="comment-insert-text" style = "border: 1px solid #e1e1e1"></textarea>
                    </div>



                    <div id="{{btn_id}}" style = "margin: 2px 2px 0 0;width:26px;height: 25px;"class="comment-post-btn-wrapper"  >
                        C
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="comments-list">

                    <ul class="comments-holder-ul " id = {{ul_id}}>
                        <input type = "text" id = "btn_id1" value = "{{btn_id}}" />


                                          <li class="comment-holder" id="_1">

                                          <div class="user-img">
                                                  <img src="images/Setting-icon.png" class="user-img-pic" /> 
                                          </div>

                                          <div class="comment-body">
                                                  <h3 class="username-field" >Fixed User</h3>

                                                  <div class="comment-text">
                                                  <?php echo "{{img_id}}" ?>

                                                  </div>
                                          </div>

                                          <div class="comment-buttons-holder">
                                                  <ul>
                                                          <li class="delete-btn">[x]</li>
                                                  </ul>
                                          </div>

                                          </li>


    <!-- To display already commented posts -->  



     <?php  

    $tty= utf8_decode('{{img_id}}');   
   $tty = str_replace("'","","$tty");
     $tty1 = "'".$tty;
     $tty2 = $tty1."'";

     include 'connect.php';

     $qur = "select count(user_id) from `comments` where `img_id`=".$tty2;
     print_r ($qur);


    $number = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($qur));
 print_r($number);


     for ($k = 1; $k <= $num_of_comments2; $k++){

            {

            $smthng = new stdClass();
        $smthng->comment_id = 24;
        $smthng->Userid = 1;
        $smthng->comment = "Hard coded comments";
        $smthng->Username = "Sagar_username"; 
        //$smthng->profile_img = "images/Setting-icon.png";


        $data =  json_encode($smthng);

$ul_id = "ul218";

      $a = '1';
      $a = $a.'2';
      $comm = "Commented";

    $t = '<li class="comment-holder" id="">';
    $t = $t.'<div class="user-img">';
  //  $t = $t.'<img src="' + data.profile_img + '" class="user-img-pic" />';
    $t = $t.'</div>';
    $t =  $t.'<div class="comment-body">';
    //$t = $t.'<h3 class="username-field" >' + data.Username + '</h3>';
    $t = $t.'<div class="comment-text">'.$comm.'</div>';
    $t = $t.'</div>';
    $t = $t.'<div class="comment-buttons-holder">';
    $t = $t.'<ul>';
    $t = $t.'<li class="delete-btn">[x]</li>';
    $t = $t.'</ul>';
    $t = $t.'</div>';
    $t = $t.'</li>';



      echo $t;

            }   
      }

      ?>












                    </ul>

                </div> 
            </div>






        </div>


        {{/result}}
    </script>
```

Comment: You can use [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to extract JSON value instead of `utf8_decode`, `str_replace` and all other stuff you have done to pick the img id from your JSON data

Comment: I  tried this:   

$tty= json_decode('{{img_id}}');   
echo $tty;

It gives null

Comment: Any other options available ?

Comment: what is `{{img_id}}` where you do get it from?

Comment: I am using handlebars.js which reads the element from JSON array as :
{{#result}} echo {{img_id}}; {{/result}}

Comment: How do you pass the data from JS to PHP, is it through an AJAX request? If yes, can you show me the code?

Comment: <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="waterfall-tpl">
        {{#result}}
<?php  echo {{img_id}}; ?>

{{/result}}

Comment: The {{img_id}} resolves fine and to the same value, as I have mentioned, but then mysql array output is different.

Comment: Is it possible to POST all that you have in your script? As I'm not clear how you use/where you have the mysql_query function

Comment: I have posted the script

Comment: Are you able to help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you know JS are executed in browsers and PHP in web server. All the PHP code you have within `<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="waterfall-tpl">...</script>` will execute before it hits the browser, so `$tty= utf8_decode('{{img_id}}');` will not work as it won't have the data.

And also `{{img_id}}` is a Handlebar template variable which will get value only when it is parsed like

```
var source   = $("#waterfall-tpl").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

I hope there is another section in your code where you pass values to the Handlebar variables and parse it. Something like below,

```
var raw_template = $('#waterfall-tpl').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(raw_template);
var data = {result:[title: "Some thing here", story: "Some thing here", image: "Some thing here", img_id: "Some thing here" ... ], [title: "Some thing here", story: "Some thing here", image: "Some thing here", img_id: "Some thing here" ... ], .... };
var html = template(data);
```

I hope you have to replace `Some thing here` with appropriate data from PHP so that it work.

Comment: The problem does not seem with {{img_id}} as it is being resolved correctly. However, when it is stored into a variable $tty2 and then passed to mysql_query, it is failing.

Comment: DID U GET ANY SUCCESS?

Comment: Anyone, any help please ?